# High-level file operation library in Python?

Tags: python, directory-structure, shutil

In my Python program i heavily use [`os`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) modules for file/directory operations. I wrote many utility functions to generalize patterns, like removing all files inside a folder, temporarily change working directory, split path into fragments, recursive glob, remove all files matching regex, etc.

Is there any library for Python which has a multitude of such high-level file/directory utility functions, possibly built on top of `os` and `shutil` modules, so i can write less boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to avoid os or shutil, as I think they are intended for this particular use. I think that most other libraries will be likely to by built on top of os and shutil (like you have done).

However you might want to complement these with some other of python's built-in file handling libraries sush as `glob` and `fnmatch`.

This link collects all built in file-operation libraries http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/python-2.6/html/p04/p04c06_file1.html